# Locking MySql table or data to prevent getting same data

Tags: php, mysql, locking

I have a database with 1 million entries and 3 programs that process something with the data. The 3 programs get the data over an api call. For example 100 entries for each request. What is the best way to prevent that the programs get the same 100 entries?

I tried to update an id per program to database, but that don't solve the problem. Because if the 3 programs request data and update from one is still running it can be that other program get same data.

I have tried **LOCK TABLES** but it is the maintable in my databse. So all other processes from php and so also slow down extremly. Because table is totaly locked every few minutes.

Comment: How about assigning a random (or rotating) worker number between 1 to 3 for each entry?
Each worker requests with "where worker=<number>" and updates the processed record with worker=0

Answer (score 0):

How about an app_id column.

App 1 does this...

```
UPDATE table SET app_id=3 where app_id=NULL LIMIT 100
SELECT * FROM table WHERE app_id=1 LIMIT 100
----process and when done----
UPDATE table SET app_id=NULL where app_id=1 LIMIT 100
```

App 2 does this...

```
UPDATE table SET app_id=2 where app_id=NULL LIMIT 100
SELECT * FROM table WHERE app_id=2 LIMIT 100
----process and when done----
UPDATE table SET app_id=NULL where app_id=2 LIMIT 100
```

You can have unlimited apps and they should only get their own records. This kinda hits your DB harder. Maybe you could use a combo of memcache/stored procedures to limit db load depending on your architecture.

Another option might be able to handle this with the API. You could create a system wide global variable and store what app has what records. Anytime the API is called, it will look at the system wide variable to know if it can obtain data or from what record to start with. That might be easier on the DB.